# Excel Sheet Protection Stopping Macro

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have been using a piece of code that zooms to fit the the worksheet to the active window. However, if I add sheet protection the macro will fail. To get around this problem, I call a sub to remove the protection then reapply the protection afterwards. Is there a way to run my sub without removing and reapplying sheet protection?

Code to change zoom:

```
Sub fixScreenSize()
    Dim rngX As Range
    Dim myLastCell As Range
    Dim myLastCellAdd As String
    Dim rngToZoom As Range      

        'Get address of last cell containing data
        Set myLastCell = Cells(1, 1).SpecialCells(xlLastCell)
            myLastCellAdd = Cells(myLastCell.Row, myLastCell.Column).Address
        'Find keyword in used range
        Set rngX = Range("A1", myLastCellAdd).Find("myZoomRange", lookat:=xlPart)
        'Zoom to correct range
        Range(Cells(1, 1), rngX).Select
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = True
        Range("A1").Select

    Set myLastCell = Nothing
    Set rngX = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Remove all sheet protection
- Open the VBE (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>)
- Go to the immediate window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>)
- Type `ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="myPassword", UserInterfaceOnly:=True` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

The active worksheet is now protected with the password "myPassword", however the `UserInterfaceOnly` argument means that your code is still allowed to run on that sheet unaffected by the sheet's protection

Comment: Ah I did not know about that. Didnt really need to look for it to be honest I have always just uprotected and then reprotected. But thank you for increasing my knowledge :)

Comment: Ah, I see how that works. I have to apply protection to multiple worksheets on multiple workbooks, I take it I can just pop `UserInterfaceOnly:=True` into my Sub that adds protection to all worksheets. Thank you :)

Comment: Yes - although you don't need to run that code anymore, the idea is you use this protection method once. As your code will not encounter this error anymore there is no need to re-protect every time the workbook is opened.

Comment: Don't worry, I've already removed the part the removes then reapplies the protection. Thanks for all your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this that I know of without removing and re-adding the protection. Once the protection is set there is no way to get around a sheet protection without removing the protection.

Your way is the correct way and should not impact on performance or anything.

EDIT as it turns out there is a way. However I have always done it this way without problems.

Comment: Not true - there's a `UserInterfaceOnly` argument that can be set at design time. (Cool name btw ;) )